# check given number is binary or not in c

Tags: c, algorithm, binary

```
#include <stdio.h>

void binarytodecimal(int n);


int main() {

    int num;
    printf("Input a binary number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int copy = num, temp = 0;

    while(copy != 0) {
        temp = copy%10;

        if((temp==0) || (temp==1)) {
            copy = copy/10;
            if(copy == 0) {
                printf("valid binary number.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Not a valid binary number. Try again\n");
            main();
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code is working perfectly fine for non binary numbers and for binary number when I run it in first attempt, but when I trie to input a binary number in the second attempt, it interpreted binary number as non binary.

I am stuck at this step.

**Output shows**

```
Input a binary number: 122
Not a valid binary number. Try again
Input a binary number: 101
valid binary number.
Not a valid binary number. Try again
Input a binary number:
```

Comment: To start with : using recusion here (calling `main` from `main`)  is a very bad idea.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen -- it's okay in C, not in C++.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It's allowed in C, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea. All code I have seen that does this, was either fun code or poorly designed code.

Comment: Binary, decimal, octal, hexadecimal, etc. are all ways of representing values **as text**. It's only when you want to convert text to a value or convert a value to text that you care about what base the text representation is using; the value doesn't care.

Comment: @Sanjay Singh is your definition of "binary number" this: _a number whose decimal representation only contains the digits '1' and '0'_ ?

Comment: @Sanjay Despite of being poorly designed your code appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said using `main()` for a recursive routine is not the best idea, you might aswell make a separate function to do the same thing without that pesky `main()` recursive call.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void check_binary(int *num) {
    int copy, temp = 0;
    printf("Input a binary number: ");
    scanf("%d", num);
    copy = *num;

    while (copy != 0) {
        temp = copy % 10;

        if ((temp == 0) || (temp == 1)) {
            copy = copy / 10;
            if (copy == 0)
            {
                printf("valid binary number.\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Not a valid binary number. Try again\n");
            check_binary(num);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int num; //variable will be saved for future use
    check_binary(&num);
    return 0;
}
```

[**Live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/rJf_izaHL)